# =WEBSERVICE Call from Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What would the VBA command be for calling the =WEBSERVICE function independent of the WorkBook or Worksheet?

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to use `Application.Evaluate("=WEBSERVICE(...)")`

Comment: @TimWilliams, I hope I am using the correct syntax for the Evaluate method.

Answer (score -1):

you may try `application.WorksheetFunction.WebService(url)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.webservice